# Java cannot find symbol for scanner

Tags: java

I am trying to make this code work and  it keep sending the error to the scaner.
(Test.java:7: error: cannot find symbol)

```
class Test{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        x = in.nextInt();

        if (x<100)
           x=x +5; 

        if (x<500)
           x=x-2; 

        if (x>10)
           x++;  
        else
           x--;  
        System.out.println(x);

}

}
```

Comment: `import java.util.Scanner;` in your code

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Answer (score 2):

Correct your code to `import java.util.Scanner;` class like below and also change `in.nextInt()` to `scanner.nextInt()`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number");

        x = scanner.nextInt();

        if (x < 100)
        {
            x = x + 5;
        }

        if (x < 500)
        {
            x = x - 2;
        }

        if (x > 10)
        {
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            x--;
        }

        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You have used `Scanner`class to take input while, you haven't told java that you are using it. For This you should import this `import java.util.Scanner`.

**2.** The class which has `public static void main(String[] args)` should be public.[why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617952/why-a-class-containg-a-main-method-doesnt-need-to-be-public-in-java)

**3.** I think you should use `if-else-if` construct instead of many `if` because in your case if `x = 20` it will be modified in all the three cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Java doc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

You will see that `Scanner` needs:

```
import java.util.Scanner
```

and not

```
import java.io.*
```